# FFMPEG watermark scale

Tags: php, ffmpeg, watermark

Im trying to set watermark scale to 0.9 or 0.7 and ... 
how to do it with this code?

```
exec("ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -i logo.png \
-filter_complex \"overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2\" watermarked.mp4");
```

Comment: Not clear. Do you want the watermark to be 90 or 70 **%** of the video?

Comment: @mulvya no .. watermark 0.7(70%) of the logo

Comment: I dont want to scale video ! just scale watermark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this command to scale the watermark to 70%:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex \
      "[1]scale=iw*0.7:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2" watermarked.mp4
```

---

To also change opacity of the PNG logo, use

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex \
      "[1]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5,scale=iw*0.7:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2" watermarked.mp4
```

Comment: and how to add opacity option to logo? for example 50% transparency opacity for logo